# How to save and run python function in HTML button? (Django - Python )

Tags: python, django

Context: For a face recognition project, user should upload a selfie and that pic will be saved in a S3 bucket (AWS) so the final result will be a template with that selfie and the person who looks like you.

So, I want a button that save the image uploaded by user and at the same time, run the face recognition function.

template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" action="{% url 'erp:fibocal' %}">  
 <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" onclick="showLoaderOnClick('{% url 'erp:fibocal' %}')">
       <i class="fas fa-save"></i>
                  ¡Encontrá tu parecido!                   
    </button>  
 </div> 
</form>
```

And that button don´t save the image in my s3 bucket, only runs "erp:fibocal" that is a function in views.py:

```
def fibocal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img_loaded = request.FILES['image']        
        imagenes = FR(img_loaded)
        return render(request, 'base.html', {'name': imagenes[0], 'prct':imagenes[1]})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home/register.html', {})
```

"imagenes" is the face recognition function and "img_loaded" is the image uploaded by the user.

I think that I should save the image at the "fibocal" function but I don´t know how.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to call python function inside html. You can use AJAX to make a request.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t mention this, I'm using Django.